# Can I use Monstache with ingest node?

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, logstash, monstache

I am looking for options to sync and enrich documents from MongoDB to Elasticsearch. I found [Monstache](https://rwynn.github.io/monstache-site/start/) that can do the sync part. I also found Elasticsearch [Ingest Node](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.4/ingest.html) that can modify the documents before indexing into Elasticsearch.

Can I use Monstache to index documents through the ingest node so that I can transform and enrich documents before storing in Elasticsearch?

There are other options like logstash, but the MongoDB plugin is not actively maintained and has quite a lot of issues. So, I am looking at other options.

Answer (score 0):

The question has been answered in Github:https://github.com/rwynn/monstache/issues/310

The idea is to set the [default pipeline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/index-modules.html#dynamic-index-settings) in index. So each documents will go through the default pipeline before indexing into Elasticsearch.